# Make it clearer what is going on with the "This content is not allowed" functionality

Tags: feature-request, user-experience, title, error-message

In reference to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59557465/revisions), I tried to edit the title to this:

> Kotlin Error Reading Phone Contacts

and got the above mentioned error.

There's no clear indication of what the problem is, and since the original title (before my edit) was

> Hello Everyone :). Please, Can anybody help me -> Kotlin Error Reading Phone Contacts

and since this title works:

> Kotlin Reading Phone Contacts

I'm calling shenanigans.

The exact error message was `Title cannot contain "Kotlin Error Reading Phone Contacts".`

Please fix the UI so that it's clear what the pr0blem actually is so that users can readily fix it, instead of trying to play Whack a Mole with the wording until something sticks.

Comment: I believe that the exact issue is intentionally not displayed, in order to prevent users from making trivial, cosmetic changes to skirt the filter without actually addressing the core issue.

Comment: Which means that you're asking a machine that isn't smart enough to understand the core issues to make decisions for users who, had they known what the core issue was, wouldn't have tried posting the title in the first place.  In the meantime, the UI is hobbled for those of us trying to make things better without a degree in regexes or access to the ones being used.

Comment: FWIW from editing old questions I suspect "error" combined with a short title length triggered the block because most new users putting "error" in a title have it otherwise hopelessly vague.

Comment: Length matters ... 41 is the magic number ...

Comment: FWIW I would use whole error message as title: Title cannot contain "Kotlin Error Reading Phone Contacts" When I am searching for errors I usually Google for the whole thing. It would be easier to spot full message in search results than partial one.

Comment: Yes, editing titles is borked....

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar: As you can see by looking at the post, there are larger problems with it than just the title.

Comment: Eh... Yes, post itself is whole different story...